# Is social life singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

A question from a student:

> This can have a detrimental effect on people's social life.

Should this be social lives?

Comment: Although the answer is unaccepted, try going through **[this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263046/people-are-is-which-one-is-correct)**

Answer (score 2):

If we are speaking about general public and social relationship then the correct is "*people's social life*". If we are talking about an individual's interpersonal relationships with others then such can exist in many, thus "*people's social lives*" is correct.

Which way one is thinking it is either for one to decide or for one to understand from given context.